# How to solve this anti-pattern: calling method in template

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, primeng, p-dropdown

I am using a p-dropdown from PrimeNG and i have to display the updated values.

At the moment in my HTML in the `p-dropdown` i typed this:

```
[options]="getReportTypes()"
```

In my typescript I have this situation:

```
reports: ReportTemplateGroupList | undefined;
@Input() set reportGroup(reportGroup: ReportTemplateGroupList | undefined | null) {
  if (reportGroup) {
    this.reports = reportGroup;
  }
  this.setReportTypeAndSubset();
}


getReportTypes(): ReportType[] {
  const reportTypes: ReportType[] = [];
  this.reports?.forEach((report) => {
    if (report.name) {
      reportTypes.push({ label: report.name });
    }
  });
  return reportTypes;
}
```

This is an anti-pattern since i'm calling a method in the template. I'm trying to find a way to update the values in another manner: for example with an Observable but I'm not able to do it since everything is still really new to me. Do you have any idea how to implement it?

I can't just simply store the value in a variable because I need that constantly updated value so it should be something that is permanently "called" in my template

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simply store the returned value of `getReportTypes()` method to a property (eg. `reportTypes`) and pass that property inside HTML to the child component. That's the way to prevent calling `getReportTypes()` in template every time change detection runs.

```
public reportTypes: ReportType[] = [];

getReportTypes(): ReportType[] {
this.reports?.forEach((report) => {
  if (report.name) {
    this.reportTypes.push({ label: report.name });
  }
});
```

In the template just simply:   `[options]="reportTypes"`

Example with `ngOnChanges()`:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
 if (changes.reportGroup) {
  this.getReportTypes();
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer, I can't do this because i constantly need to get that updated value

Comment: Hi, you are welcome. Then you might consider using `ngOnChanges` lifecycle method and there you would "listen" to input changes and call `getReportTypes()` upon them. :)

Comment: Perfect, and how can I listen to the input changes? I just know that with the ngOnChanges I can listen to the @Input() changes so in my case the "reportGroup" ones. I can then call the getReportTypes() method in the "ngOnChanges" right?

Comment: Exactly! I will write an example in the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chaka, I will then accept yours, in the meanwhile I upvoted ^_^